Install Ubuntu on a surface pro 4 - /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sda: no medium found
I try to install Ubuntu on a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 with Windows already installed.
I have a big part of the disk that is not used (free space).
When I start on my USB stick, I get the initial screen, where I can choose to try/install Ubuntu.
And then there is this error message on the CLI:
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sda: no medium found

I've tried to reinstall the USB stick with different devices and ISO, different OS... But always the same message.
Before wiping this Surface Pro, I would know if there is another solution.
Thanks for your help.

This question is similar to: Problems installing Ubuntu stdin: Invalid argument. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, I haven't seen that post. I will try and edit or close this post in consequence. Thank you for your help @karel.

In my case, the problem was hardware-related. I didn’t check whether it was an issue with the USB stick or the USB bus. Sometimes, my USB stick in the live OS was not recognized properly. Here’s what I did: When booting from the live USB and seeing the spinner, press F2 to enable console output. Once the errors start appearing, unplug the USB stick and reconnect it, or try a different USB port. In my case, this resolved the issue.
